# Count String A with respect to Grouped String B

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns Column A Has grouped Names and Column B has kinds of Relationships

I need to count all the kinds of Relationships: Self, Boss, Peer, Direct Report, Other for each Name in column A

I can count ALL the Relationships with the Sub below but I can not find or figure out how to count with respect to the name group.

The names constantly change so I can not hard code them

Example

```
Betty Sue Self(1) Boss(1) Peer(3) Direct Report(1) Other(1)
```

Thanks

In column A I have "Grouped Names

```
Betty Sue
Betty Sue
Betty Sue
Betty Sue
Betty Sue
Betty Sue
Fred Anderson
Fred Anderson
Fred Anderson
Molly Capra
Molly Capra
Molly Capra
Molly Capra
Molly Capra
```

In Column B I have Relationships

```
Self
Boss
Peer
Peer
Other
Direct Report
Peer
Self
Peer
Direct Report
Direct Report
Direct Report
Boss
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a pivot table for this?

Comment: Good idea Alistair I did not consider that, Thanks Tim

Comment: [How to create Pivot , Dynamic Data Source, Grouping Data  & more](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot01.html)

Comment: Also look at 'filtering for unique values'.

Comment: Since you found a solution, you should move the solution from the question to the answer so that the question appears 'answered'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with Alistair's sugestion of a pivot table I have this as well

Prints to the page

```
Dim Str     As String
Set Rng = range(range("A1"), range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = 1
For Each Dn In Rng
        If Not Dic.exists(Dn.Value) Then
            Set Dic(Dn.Value) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If

        If Not Dic(Dn.Value).exists(Dn.Offset(, 3).Value) Then
            Dic(Dn.Value).Add (Dn.Offset(, 3).Value), 1
        Else
            Q = Dic(Dn.Value).Item(Dn.Offset(, 3).Value)
                Q = Q + 1
            Dic(Dn.Value).Item(Dn.Offset(, 3).Value) = Q
        End If
Next Dn
Dim C As Integer
Dim Ac As Integer
C = 4
For Each k In Dic.Keys
   C = C + 1
   Ac = 1
   Cells(Ac, C) = k
        For Each p In Dic(k)
           Ac = Ac + 1
            Cells(Ac, C) = p & " (" & Dic(k).Item(p) & ")"
        Next p
Next k
End Sub
```

Shows in a MessageBox

```
Sub Report()
Dim Dn      As range
Dim Rng     As range
Dim Dic     As Object
Dim Q       As Variant
Dim k       As Variant
Dim p       As Variant
Dim Str     As String
Set Rng = range(range("A2"), range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = 1
For Each Dn In Rng
        If Not Dic.exists(Dn.Value) Then
            Set Dic(Dn.Value) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If

        If Not Dic(Dn.Value).exists(Dn.Offset(, 1).Value) Then
            Dic(Dn.Value).Add (Dn.Offset(, 1).Value), 1
        Else
            Q = Dic(Dn.Value).Item(Dn.Offset(, 1).Value)
                Q = Q + 1
            Dic(Dn.Value).Item(Dn.Offset(, 1).Value) = Q
        End If
Next Dn

For Each k In Dic.Keys
   Str = Str & k & " :- "
        For Each p In Dic(k)
           Str = Str & p & " (" & Dic(k).Item(p) & ") , "
        Next p
    Str = Str & Chr(10)
Next k
MsgBox Str
End Sub
```